# Handle escaped characters in tooltip

Tags: html, asp.net, unicode, resx

I have an application in ASP.NET Mvc that has different `.resx` files for different locales.

I have a button that has a tooltip that's supposed to be localized

```
<button title="@MyResxFile.Tooltip">
...
</button>
```

This is the value that I have in the `.resx` file for Spanish

[image]

This is the text that's displayed in the actual website when you hover over the button

```
Categor&#237;a
```

This only happens in tooltips. Text that's placed directly on the page doesn't suffer from it.

Is there a general solution for this that would apply for the entire website? I have a lot of tooltips that suffer from this problem.

Comment: Turns out it's a problem with Vue (I have Vue templates embedded in my site). Created a separate post for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66462353/vue-handle-non-english-characters-in-an-attribute