# Vue - Handle non English characters in an attribute

Tags: vue.js, unicode, resx, non-ascii-characters

I have a Vue app that is hosted in an ASP.NET MVC server

Inside one of my Vue templates, I have this code

```
<button title="@MyResxFile.Tooltip">
...
</button>
```

Everything works fine when I'm in English
But whenever I change the site language to something else (e.g. Spanish) that contains non ascii characters, This is the text that I get when I hover over the button

```
Categor&#237;a
```

(Supposed to be `Categoría`)

This happens only inside a Vue template, parts of the site which don't use Vue, don't suffer from that problem.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `v-html` ([wiki](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)) directive. If you have the correct charset it should work fine. But be careful with this directive. XSS attacks can be very dangerous.

Hope it fixes your problem.

Comment: As far as I see, the `v-html` allows me to replace whatever is inside the element, no inside a specific attribute (e.g. `title`). Are you sure I can use it here?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in `vue-router` for non english characters (ex: Persian), the solution is to use `decodeURI('Categoría')`.